# Sample a random integer in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

This might be a very easy question, but I can't really find it. How can I sample a random integer between 1 and N in Rcpp? I know I can sample a uniform number and round it, or include the `sample` function to use in the C++ code, but both don't seem like the correct way of doing this.

Comment: I think it is a acceptable way to sample uniformly and round then (as long as the probabilities for 1 and N are the same as for all other values in between)

Comment: http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2012/09/02/

Answer (score 8):

1. AFIACR we do not have a "decent" (ie vectorised) `sample()` function in Rcpp-land, but Christian Gunning is working on one based on Armadillo via RcppArmadillo.
2. You can of course sample from U(0,1), scale to N and to the rest. We have `R::runif()` for the scalar case and `runif()` in sugar which is vectorised.

*Edit:* As of 2017, both RcppArmadillo and Rcpp now have a `sample()` function.