# Generating a random bit stream in Rcpp efficiently

Tags: c++, r, random, rcpp, r-package

I have an auxiliary function in the R package I'm currently building named `rbinom01`. Note that it calls `random(3)`.

```
int rbinom01(int size) {
  if (!size) {
    return 0;
  }

  int64_t result = 0;
  while (size >= 32) {
    result += __builtin_popcount(random());
    size -= 32;
  }

  result += __builtin_popcount(random() & ~(LONG_MAX << size));

  return result;
}
```

When `R CMD check my_package`, I got the following warning:

```
* checking compiled code ... NOTE
File ‘ my_package/libs/my_package.so’:
  Found ‘_random’, possibly from ‘random’ (C)
    Object: ‘ my_function.o’

Compiled code should not call entry points which might terminate R nor
write to stdout/stderr instead of to the console, nor use Fortran I/O
nor system RNGs.

See ‘Writing portable packages’ in the ‘Writing R Extensions’ manual.
```

I headed to [the Document](https://cran.rstudio.com/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Random-numbers), and it says I can use one of the `*_rand` function, along with a family of [distribution functions](https://cran.rstudio.com/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Distribution-functions). Well that's cool, but my package simply needs a stream of random bits rather than a random `double`. The easiest way I can have it is by using `random(3)` or maybe reading from `/dev/urandom`, but that makes my package "unportable".

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853334/sample-a-random-integer-in-rcpp) suggests using `sample`, but unfortunately it doesn't fit into my use case. For my application, generating random bits is apparently critical to the performance, so I don't want it waste any time calling `unif_rand`, multiply the result by `N` and round it. Anyway, the reason I'm using C++ is to exploit bit-level parallelism.

Surely I can hand-roll my own PRNG or copy and paste the code of a state-of-the-art PRNG like [xoshiro256**](http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it), but before doing that I would like to see if there are any easier alternatives.

Incidentally, could someone please link a nice short tutorial of Rcpp to me? *Writing R Extensions* is comprehensive and awesome but it would take me weeks to finish. I'm looking for a more concise version, but preferably it should be more informative than a call to `Rcpp.package.skeleton`.

---

As suggested by [@Ralf Stubner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8416610/ralf-stubner)'s answer, I have re-wrote the original code as follow. However, I'm getting the same result every time. How can I seed it properly and at the same time keep my code "portable"?

```
int rbinom01(int size) {
  dqrng::xoshiro256plus rng;

  if (!size) {
    return 0;
  }

  int result = 0;
  while (size >= 64) {
    result += __builtin_popcountll(rng());
    Rcout << sizeof(rng()) << std::endl;
    size -= 64;
  }

  result += __builtin_popcountll(rng() & ((1LLU << size) - 1));

  return result;
}
```

Comment: You can get xoshiro256+ and xoroshiro128+ via the [dqrng](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dqrng) package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different R packages that make PRNGs available as C++ header only libraries:

- [BH](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BH): Everything from `boost.random`
- [sitmo](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sitmo): Various Threefry versions
- [dqrng](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dqrng): PCG family, xoshiro256+ and xoroshiro128+
- ...

You can make use of any of these by adding `LinkingTo` to your package's `DECRIPTION`. Typically these PRNGs are modeled after the C++11 `random` header, which means you have to control their life-cycle and seeding yourself. In a single-threaded environment I like to use anonymous namespaces for life-cycle control, e.g.:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(dqrng)]]
#include <xoshiro.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

namespace {
dqrng::xoshiro256plus rng{};
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void set_seed(int seed) {
  rng.seed(seed);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int rbinom01(int size) {
  if (!size) {
    return 0;
  }

  int result = 0;
  while (size >= 64) {
    result += __builtin_popcountll(rng());
    size -= 64;
  }

  result += __builtin_popcountll(rng() & ((1LLU << size) - 1));

  return result;
}

/*** R
set_seed(42)
rbinom01(10)
rbinom01(10)
rbinom01(10)
*/
```

However, using `runif` isn't all bad and certainly faster than accessing `/dev/urandom`. In `dqrng` there is a [convenient wrapper](https://github.com/daqana/dqrng/blob/master/inst/include/R_randgen.h) for this.

As for tutorials: Besides WRE the [Rcpp package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf) vignette is a must read. [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) by Hadley Wickham also has a chapter on "compiled code" if you want to go the `devtools`-way.

Comment: Four :)  RcppZiggurat.

Comment: @Dirk Does RcppZiggurat give access to the underlying bit stream? I thought it "only" provided super-fast normal variates.

Comment: True. The original paper also has exponentials, but I don't cover that.

Comment: `dqrng` looks like a decent package, but I don't think it's exporting the underlaying `xoshiro128+` to me. The reference manual just mentioned it have things like `dqrunif` which doesn't return a bit stream. Are you suggesting me to use `generateSeedVectors` from C++? Please show me a minimal example if that's the case.

Comment: I think I've figured out myself, but there are still some issues concerning seeding. Please take a look at my edited question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately it doesn't work. `fatal error: 'convert_seed.h' file not found`. This file isn't present in `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5.1-MRO/Resources/library/dqrng/include/`. Am I missing any dependency?

Comment: @nalzok That header was included in [version 0.1.0](http://www.daqana.org/dqrng/news/index.html#dqrng-0-1-0). Depending on the MRAN date used, that might be to recent for your MRO installation. Simple solution is to not use it and restrict yourself to seeding with 32 bits. I will update the code accordingly ...

Comment: Ah I see. Just for the record, you can use `options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com"))` to download the latest package on CRAN. (The URL is basically "a standard CRAN mirror that refreshes daily")